# Arduino + Ultimate GPS Shield + Xbee Shield + Xbee

Tags: gps, arduino, xbee

I wanna make a project using an Arduino UNO R3 + Ultimate GPS Shield (with built in gps) from Adafruit + Xbee Shield + Xbee S2 and another Arduino MEGA with just Xbee Shield + Xbee module

The following code is the library from adafruit to output gps data in the console using a baud rate of 115200. MY problem is that the xbee becomes unrecongisable (using XCTU) with this kind of code thus i cant configure it.

My question is does my xbee still work even though its not recognisable or i have a problem with the softwareSerial pins or something?

Note that the gps works and outputs data okay.

```
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 7);
SoftwareSerial xbeeSerial(2,3);

Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);

#define GPSECHO  false

boolean usingInterrupt = false;
void useInterrupt(boolean); // Func prototype keeps Arduino 0023 happy

void setup()  
{

 Serial.begin(115200);
 xbeeSerial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Adafruit GPS library basic test!");


 GPS.begin(9600);


 GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
 GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);   // 1 Hz update rate
 GPS.sendCommand(PGCMD_ANTENNA);
 useInterrupt(true);

 delay(1000);
 mySerial.println(PMTK_Q_RELEASE);
}


SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
 char c = GPS.read();

#ifdef UDR0
 if (GPSECHO)
   if (c) UDR0 = c;  

#endif
}

void useInterrupt(boolean v) {
 if (v) {

   OCR0A = 0xAF;
   TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
   usingInterrupt = true;
 } else {

   TIMSK0 &= ~_BV(OCIE0A);
   usingInterrupt = false;
 }
}

uint32_t timer = millis();
void loop()                     // run over and over again
{

 if (! usingInterrupt) {

   char c = GPS.read();

   if (GPSECHO)
     if (c) Serial.print(c);
 }


 if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {


   if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
     return;  // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for another
 }


 if (timer > millis())  timer = millis();


 if (millis() - timer > 2000) { 
   timer = millis(); // reset the timer

   Serial.print("\nTime: ");
   Serial.print(GPS.hour, DEC); Serial.print(':');
   Serial.print(GPS.minute, DEC); Serial.print(':');
   Serial.print(GPS.seconds, DEC); Serial.print('.');
   Serial.println(GPS.milliseconds);
   Serial.print("Date: ");
   Serial.print(GPS.day, DEC); Serial.print('/');
   Serial.print(GPS.month, DEC); Serial.print("/20");
   Serial.println(GPS.year, DEC);
   Serial.print("Fix: "); Serial.print((int)GPS.fix);
   Serial.print(" quality: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.fixquality); 
   if (GPS.fix) {
     Serial.print("Location: ");
     Serial.print(GPS.latitude, 4); Serial.print(GPS.lat);
     Serial.print(", "); 
     Serial.print(GPS.longitude, 4); Serial.println(GPS.lon);
     Serial.print("Location (in degrees, works with Google Maps): ");
     Serial.print(GPS.latitudeDegrees, 4);
     Serial.print(", "); 
     Serial.println(GPS.longitudeDegrees, 4);

     Serial.print("Speed (knots): "); Serial.println(GPS.speed);
     Serial.print("Angle: "); Serial.println(GPS.angle);
     Serial.print("Altitude: "); Serial.println(GPS.altitude);
     Serial.print("Satellites: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.satellites);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you can't configure the XBee using X-CTU when it's installed in the shield on the Arduino?  Your code doesn't seem to be doing anything with that serial port other than opening it.  Just configure the XBee with an XBee USB adapter or some other dev board, and then install it in the Arduino.  Also consider running the XBee at 115200bps as well -- you'll get better performance if you're pushing any significant amount of data.

Comment: no what i am saying actually is that the code block "serial.begin()" even with just that code in my sketch it makes the xbee module unrecognisable in XCTU for some reason.But if i use an empty sketch or something else than that xbee is recognisable!Do i need to configure serial pins somewhere in the XCTU configuration or something?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the XBee shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoXbeeShield) seems to imply that that's expected behavior:

> With the jumpers in the USB position (i.e. on the two pins nearest the
>   edge of the board), the DOUT pin the Xbee module is connected to the
>   RX pin of the FTDI chip, and DIN on the Xbee module is connected to
>   the TX pin of the FTDI chip. This means that the Xbee module can
>   communicate directly with the computer - however, this only works if
>   the microcontroller has been removed from the Arduino board. If the
>   microcontroller is left in the Arduino board, it will be able to talk
>   to the computer normally via USB, but neither the computer nor the
>   microcontroller will be able to talk to the Xbee module.

If the XBee shield has its jumper in the "USB" position so you can communicate with X-CTU, you can't make use of that serial port in your running Arduino program.

Comment: thank you ,there is a switch on the shield i can switch it from USB to Direct and i can communicate with xbees!